# Why do some libraries define their own pointer types?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was using PCL today and noticed a certain datatype: `pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr`

What purpose does something like this serve that a `pcl::PointCloud<T>*`, `pcl::PointCloud<T>&`, or even a `std::shared_ptr<PointCloud<T>>` does not?

If there was additional logic implemented for the deference operation, couldn't the operator just be overridden?

Comment: Could be used mostly internally, an then `Ptr` would be much shorter to write. Also, it could be something completely different than the alternatives you list (i.e. a pointer to something other).

Comment: For one, code-readability is improved

Answer (score 2):

Libraries often do their own memory management, which could be wrapped by a custom smart pointer, especially if the library was invented before C++11 standardized smart pointers.

This is confirmed by looking at the [pcl::PointCloud< T > Class Template Reference](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html), where the following declaration can be found:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr< PointCloud< PointT > > Ptr;
```

When the library devs and their users consistently use `PointCloud< PointT >::Ptr`, it will make it easier for them to switch to a different smart pointer class (e. g. `std::shared_ptr`) in the future.